# Mosaicking of touchless fingerprint images by finding the stitching line in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fingerprint, image-stitching, mosaic

I am trying to increase the effective fingerprint region by trying to stitch two fingerprint images (left and center) taken by two different cameras. Images have been attached below. I tried the standard process of image mosaicking and it gives a erroneous result.The reason I feel is that, the two images contain the entire fingerprint and not a part of the fingerprint.

The center image:

[image: center image]

The left image:

[image: left image]

The mosaic image:

[image: mosaic image]

The solution to this problem was explained in the following [paper](http://cherup.yonsei.ac.kr/files/Paper/Mosaicing%20Touchless%20and%20Mirror-Reflected%20Fingerprint%20Images%20(2010).pdf).

In this they have tried to get the stitching line and mosaic the images based on it.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain me the process to get the stitching line in matlab?

EDIT
[image: Image for region of interest]

The code is

```
[x1,x2,x3,x4]=findroi(matches_geo,frames1,frames2);


   function [x1,x2,x3,x4] = findroi(matches,f1,f2)
   for i = 1:size(matches,2)
      xpos1(i) = f1(1,matches(1,i));
      xpos2(i) = f2(1,matches(2,i));
      x1 = max(xpos1);
      x2 = min(xpos1);
      x3 = max(xpos2);
      x4 = min(xpos2);
    end
```

The matching is done based on the sift features. I get the rectangle by finding the maximum and minimum values of the x-coordinate. The next step would be to find the stitching line to combine the two images.

Comment: So you're basically asking for an implementation of the paper?

Comment: @naveh- No, I am not asking for the implementation of the paper. I am using 3 cameras for taking the images while the paper takes only 1 camera and mirror reflections for images. But I am stuck at the part where it comes to stitching. The paper mentions that they take the stitching line, but I do not know on what basis we are supposed to take and stitch it. Anything regarding this would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Got it, so it's a specific part of the paper you are trying to emulate. What have you done so far? Can you post your code?